# External keyboard and ESC key on Android

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, termux, text-input, text-editor

https://www.logitech.com/en-hk/product/k580-multi-device-wireless-keyboard

This bluetooth keyboard (probably many others) has the back tick `` ` `` and `Esc` keys on it. Will these `` ` `` and `Esc` work on Android Apps such as Termux with Vim? Linux on Dex?

I think External Keyboard Helper Pro is an app that can help with this as well browsing the Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work.if virtual keyboard with ``` /`` and ``` esc` worked then why not hardware keyboard worked it will work.